# Task.Factory.StartNew is not invoking the method

Tags: c#, multitasking

I am new to C# concurrency and trying a basic application with two buttons, first button click should fire a method which goes through a for loop and next button click even should cancel

```
Task t;
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
bool cancelPressed = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;
    t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Count(token), token);

    if (cancelPressed)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    tasks.Add(t);
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private void Count(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int a = Int32.MinValue; a < Int32.MinValue; a++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancelPressed = true;
}
```

but it the `Count()` is not getting fired. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

your loop condition is wrong causing the code inside the loop not to be excuted , change `a < Int32.MinValue` to `a < Int32.MaxValue`

like so :

```
for (int a = Int32.MinValue; a < Int32.MaxValue; a++)
```